# Unable to Host my React NodeJS app on Heroku

Tags: heroku

I am trying to host my react app with a NodeJS server on Heroku, but I keep getting `H10` Error, can someone please help resolve it.

Our nodeJS server seems to be working fine [Node Server endpoint](https://curie-video-react-comet-chat1.herokuapp.com/ping) but not the [React app](https://curie-video-react-comet-chat1.herokuapp.com/).

Here is the code for scripts in the `package.json` file. I guess I got the scripts wrong. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently npm:server npm:dev",
    "local": "concurrently npm:server npm:dev",
    "dev": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "node ./scripts/build.js",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "postinstall": "node ./postinstall.js",
    "server": "nodemon server/server.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm install && npm run build"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Im i'm assuming correctly there are two sets of package.json files and that your express server is serving up client files.

There should be one package.json in your **server** folder, and one in the **client**.

In my heroku projects I have this line of code in my **server package.json** to allow deployment.

```
"heroku-postbuild": "npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
```

let me know if that solved the issue!